# Finding the Norton current

Tags: norton

We are asked to find the Norton current or short-circuit current (Isc). I have managed to find v2 = 3V and Norton resistance is 4Ω. My book says Isc = v2/R3 but doesn't explain why. Is there any explaination for this or any other way to find the Norton current? Thank you for your help.[image]

Comment: If you have `v2`, then what is the voltage drop on `R3` ?

Comment: Is the voltage drop v2?

Comment: Sure it is. It is v2 on the left and zero on the right, as connected to ground. So what is the current through it?

Comment: There are two V2.2.0 in the diagram. Which one should be used?

Answer (score 1):

\$V_2\$ uses single subscript notation which implies a ground reference. When nodes a and b are connected together (shorted) the node a side of \$R_3\$ is connected to ground.

Thus the voltage across \$R_3\$ is \$V_2\$, hence \$I_{sc}=\frac{V_2}{R_3}\$.

Answer (score 0):

Explanation: That is the Ohms law. You need the current through R3 with given potential difference from v2 to a; a has the same electrical potential as b and GND.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it by applying Kirchhoff's Current Law at nodes v1 and v2, knowing that v2-v1 = 6V.
Alternatively, you can apply the Superposition Theorem to find Isc (short circuit the voltage source and calculate Isc1. Then open the current source and calculate Isc2). So Isc = Isc1 + Isc2.

Using the first method:
node v1:
2 -V1 / 6 - i =0 (equation 1) 
node v2:
i - v2 / 3 - v2 / 2 = 0  (equation 2) 
v2 - v1 = 6V  (equation 3) 
Solving the system of equations, we get V2 = 3V and V1 = -3V. 
 Therefore, Isc = v2/R3. Norton resistance (Rn) is obtained by "looking" between points "a" and "b", short-circuiting the voltage source and opening the current source, result Rn = 4 Ohms.